# Combinatorics of Experiment Design

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

**Background**

I’ve had to make some of these by hand for a science experiment and was checking to see if anybody had any clever ways of achieving this. It feels like sudoku, but not quite. figuring out a generic way to generate one of these been bugging me for a while. It seems easy to verify but hard to generate. I have no idea how to gauge the state space of this problem or how to approach how to start generating the design in a non heuristic way.
I've looked a bit at Block Design as well but this problem has slightly more constraints and doesn't seem to completely apply.

I'm not a math person so let me know if I am explaining this poorly.

N is typically anywhere from 5 - 20 but can vary.

**Problem**

for N subjects and 8 trials, generate N x 8 experiments for 5 possible positions such that:

1. minimizes the difference in the number of times each subject sees another across trials.
   1a. each subject needs to see every other subject at least once IN a trial.

Ex. For the following two experiments, `1` has *seen* `[2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13]` once, and vice versa.

```
    [1,2,3,4,5]
    [10,1,11,12,13]
```

2. ensures that each subject participates in each position (column) at least once in each trial.  The following shows 5 experiments in which `1` has been in each position at least once.

   ```
   [1,#,#,#,#]
   [#,1,#,#,#]
   [#,#,1,#,#]
   [#,#,#,1,#]
   [#,#,#,#,1]
   ```
3. Each experiment is a unique set (ABCDE == BADCE) unless constraint 2 still needs to be satisfied. (relevant when N is small). The following is not allowed.

   ```
   [1,2,3,4,5]
   [1,3,4,2,5]
   ```

Each subject (assigned a number) is in each position denoted by the columns, at least once.

Input should be number of teams N

Output should be N x 8 Rows(representing experiments) that meet the above constraints.

The heuristic behind this is to find the "Best Value" of all the permutations without having to actually RUN every single permutation.

**Examples**

output for 1 (out of 8) trials with test cases for N = 10:
in python

```
l = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,1,7,8,9],
    [10,3,1,6,7],
    [2,6,4,1,10],
    [3,4,6,7,2],
    [4,7,10,2,8],
    [5,8,2,9,3],
    [7,9,5,3,1],
    [9,5,8,10,4],
    [8,10,4,5,6]
]
```

test cases

```
def matchup(l):
    d = { i:{x:0 for x in range(1,11) if x != i} for i in range(1,11)}
    for g in l:
        for e in g:
            for eo in g:
                if eo != e:
                    d[e][eo] += 1

    mx = max([
    max(g.values()) for g in d.values()
    ])
    mn = min([
    min(g.values()) for g in d.values()
    ])

    print('diff matchup: {}-{}'.format(mx,mn))

def set_c(l):
""" checks if a set is used more than once 
"""
    sl =  [frozenset(g) for g in l]
    diff = len(set(sl))
    if diff == 10:
        print('sets ok')
    else:
        print('sets not ok')
```